# How can I use DDE with Javascript without using Active X?

Tags: javascript, dde

I'm trying to find a way to do the equivalent of

```
comm = window.event.srcElement._command;
if(comm){
    xlApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var app = xlApp.DDEInititate(".....", "....");
    xlApp.DDEExecute(app,comm);
    xlApp.DDETerminate(app);
    app = "";
    xlApp.Quit();
}
```

without the use of an activeX object. Are there any frameworks out there that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure JavaScript can't communicate with other applications or shared libraries.

EDIT: You might be able to do it with a [Java applet] (with extra permissions), and there are ways to communicate between Java and JavaScript.

Comment: so is there no alternative to ActiveX?

Comment: Signed Java applets would be able to download and execute any program with full privileges, which is definitely enough to be able to send DDE messages.